# .htaccess redirect one level if string exists in URL

Tags: .htaccess

Can anyone please point me to a tutorial or article or give a solution (with some explanation)  on how to redirect one level up if certain string exists at the end of the URL.

For example

http://www.example.com/s/texas/hello-world/

should be redirected to

http://www.example.com/s/texas/

Assume the string is 'hello-world' and I have 100 different urls

i.e
/s/florida/hello-world

/c/boston/massachusetts/hello-world  etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression below captures everything before `hello-world` inside `(.*)` as `$1` and redirects to it.  The `/?` makes the trailing slash optional.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)hello-world/?$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for the explanation and solution. You rock!